# How to get back WiFi after running sudo chmod -R a+rwx in home folder

Tags: wireless, sudo, chmod

I mistakenly ran the following command in my home folder:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx
```

Afterwards, my Wi-Fi now says `no adapter found`. How do I correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the permissions back to their default value by executing:

```
    sudo chmod -R 755 ~/
```

But I am not sure this will solve your issue as I have not tested it personally.